# Trying to understand win/loss given gambling odds

Tags: probability, definition, gambling

Let's say I know the gambling odds are $X:Y$.

I bet \$$100$. How much do I get if I win? If I lose?

I'm not quite sure how to interpret the meaning of the odds and Google is confusing.

Comment: If you're talking about fractional odds, then if team X has odds of 5/1 then whatever you put in will be multiplied by 5 if they win and vice versa.

Comment: I am trying to understand for arbitrary $X$ and $Y$, e.g. $7:4$ or something like $5:11$, not necessarily $X:1$ format

Answer (score 1):

$X$ paid for every $Y$ bet can be normalised to a $Z:1$ payout by taking $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$. For your hundred dollars you have an expectation of $\frac{100×X}{Y}$ gross return.

You can expect to win $\frac{100×(X-Y)}{Y^2}$ for each such bet, which of course is negative and therefore a loss if $X<Y$, since the first $Y$ paid back are to cover your original wager and you can only gain if the total $X$ paid back is greater than this.